# ValidationSummery Showing Message Twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I Am trying to check all validations before form submission and after submission make the button disabled to prevent Multiple submission. All this is working properly the only problem is it will showing me validation summery twice

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
                  function ValidateFirst(btn) {
                      var validate = true;
                      if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                          Page_ClientValidate('Submit');
                          validate = ValidatorOnSubmit();
                      }
                      if (validate)    //disable button only if page is valid and ready to submit
                      {
                          btn.value = 'Please wait...';
                          btn.disabled = true;
                      }
                      return validate;
                  }
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="button" TabIndex="23" Text="Save" ToolTip="Click to Save" ValidationGroup="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="ValidateFirst(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Page_ClientValidate() may cause the page to show multiple alerts. I would suggest you to try a custom validate function instead.